# change_column migration deletes table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, rails-migrations

I've run a `change_column` migration a couple times now and it deletes the entire table I'm trying to make the change to.

```
class ChangePictureColumnInProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  change_column :properties, :pictures, :json
end
end
```

It then just completely deletes the entire `properties` table.

I'm trying to set-up CarrierWave and the documentation says to "Add a Column that can store an array" and provides an example using JSON, to provide context on what I'm doing.

I'm new to Rails so no clue what I'm doing wrong here. Appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLite you need drop the table and create it again, SQLite doesn't support delete, change type and rename columns (without delete the entry).

In your migration,  can do:

```
drop_table :properties
create_table :properties
add_column :properties, :your_previous_columns
add_column :properties, :your_previous_columns
add_column :properties, :pictures, :json
```

If you have relevant information, can create another table with the good structure, import your information and after delete the old table.

IMPORTANT!
I don't believe that a json field would be the best option, you can use a "one to many" relationship between your entry and his images.

And when you need add images for you entry use "nested forms".

with nested forms you can send the information that belongs to your entry and his nested images.

Comment: Thanks Elias.  Tried this and same issue.  It dropped the table again.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you using sqlite?